# Do noise-cancelling headphones make a lot of unheard noise?

Tags: acoustics, interference, electronics, noise

The way noise cancelling headphones work is by listening to sound, and created the inverted sound to 'cancel it out'. Doesn't this mean that the headphones create double the amount of noise, but our ears just can't pick it up due to the noise being 'equalized'?

Comment: “how dies this common device work” isn’t exactly a physics question, but an engineering one. As such, this question is off topic here

Comment: Hmmm, not really sure. Maybe I failed to convey the real meaning of my question, but I really just want to know if the mechanism for cancelling out sound waves actually doubles it. Anyway, if I remember correctly, this question was first posted in the medical section, but it was moved by someone to the physics section. That is why the answer starts with "this question blend over into the realm of physics".

Comment: I’m aware of the migration, it says as much in a massive banner under your question. The “mechanism for cancelling” noise is exactly the not-a-physics question I mean, it’s asking how something works which is instead engineering.

Comment: Sorry, was not aware that is was visible. I'm using mobile, that's why I didn't see it.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I never use mobile site because it’s (intentionally?) limited, full site version is better (though i guess it uses more data?)

Comment: Eh, it's mostly because I have the app and I get notified of updates! Makes it easier to be more responsive. Downside is that you indeed only see a limited view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question blends over into the realm of Physics:

Yes, noise-cancelling headphones create what is known as 'anti-sound', which is (virtually) the same sound (and equally loud) as can be heard in the environment, but with an inverted phase.
This inverted sound wave indeed cancels out the original sound wave from the environment, resulting in (virtually) no air displacement at your ears: i.e. no sound, no noise.

The actual anti-sound created by real-world noise-cancelling headphones is not *exactly* the inverse sound as your surroundings, but a (close) approximation. The quality of this approximation limited by the quality and latency of the microphones, chip, software and speakers in the headphones. This means that they will only reduce and not perfectly cancel all noise.

It also means that if you have a noise that only lasts a very short time, the headphones might actually be too slow to cancel the noise. In this case, your ears will first hear the original sound (at full volume) and then the anti-sound (also at full volume). In this case you could say that the headphones have created a lot of additional noise (which in that case *will* be heard).

---

To summarize: Yes, noise-cancelling headphones are constantly making noise themselves. The net effect of this is however that the amount of noise that reaches your ears is greatly reduced.

Comment: Thank you! Is this 'anti-noise' a concern in terms of hearing damage? It's using a noise cancelling headset worse than a regular headset?

Comment: Although this looks like a good answer, it doesn't meet site requirements. We require answers to provide supporting references for assertions of fact.

Comment: @Titulum A sound is a pressure wave. If you produce an "anti-sound" the result (at the ear) is not two waves of opposite sign, there is only one "space" so only one wave, in this case a mostly flat line equal to silence.

Comment: Electronics work at nearly the speed of light, so I can't imagine there's much latency relative to the speed of sound. And there's no such thing as inverted sound.

Comment: So, in order to end this thread: Does using noise-cancelling headphones increase or decrease the risk for hearing loss compared to using non-noise-cancelling headphones?

Comment: When the noise-cancelling headphones kill the sound by producing a wave of opposity polarity (i.e., when they do what they should do), they should decrease the risk of hearing loss (due to loud sounds) considerably. Anything that *sounds* silent, *is* silent!

Comment: "Anti-sound" is not a term used in physics. The inverted sound wave has no special properties except in comparison to the original sound wave. This answer would be improved if you changed "anti-sound" everywhere to "inverted wave."

Answer (score 1):

Well, Qqwy, has provided a nice answer to you, so I am just gonna try to add up to that.

As has already been mentioned, the actual realization of an active noise cancellation device has many implications. Latency being just one of them (more of them include imperfections in modelling, the transfer function of the components, incorrect equalization and a whole bunch more).

One thing to keep in mind though is that if the source and "cancelling device" are not co-located (i.e. they do not occupy the exact same space) you cannot completely cancel the generated sound field in the whole domain of interest. This means that when the two sources' (original source and cancelling source) locations start to depart from each other you will start to have "artefacts" from the existence of the second (cancelling) source.

Some well-known techniques (used extensively in active noise control in headphones) include the cancellation of noise at a specific point in space. Keep in mind though that this, almost for sure (especially true for broadband sounds), will increase the sound pressure level in some other point in space. A different approach is concerned with the minimization of the noise power, which **does not** necessarily coincide with complete cancellation of the noise in a specific point or direction.

Now, regarding the specifics of noise-cancelling headphones, one has to also take into account the fact that the headphones themselves affect the sound field and due to diffraction, as well as other phenomena which become increasingly important in this scale (such as the viscosity close to the boundaries of both the headphone and the ear, the heat variations in case of "muffle-like" headphones and a lot more), which are very difficult to anticipate/foresee, the effectiveness of those devices/techniques can be very easily compromised.

Additionally, you have to keep in mind that this technology is effective primarily at low frequencies because in the "high-frequency regime" small variations in space can result in big variations in pressure, so any small imperfection of the equipment (or conditions) can result in doubling the pressure instead of cancelling it.

I apologize for not providing any in-text references, but those interested can find condensed information from this an article by Elliot and Nelson titled [Active Noise Control, IEEE Signal Process. Mag., October](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3321160_Active_Noise_Control_IEEE_Signal_Process_Mag_October), or books like [Active Control of Sound](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125154259) by Nelson and [Active Control of Noise and Vibration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0415590612) by Hansen et al.